# How do I run a php function in a subprocess in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, process, subprocess, symfony-process

I want to run some functions parallel in the background.

Is there a nice way to do this in Symfony2 or even with php?

Or is there only the `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`?

Can I use this Process with a function? I need the actual Context (logged in user and some session data), so it is not possible to source the function out to an external php-file...

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 Process component allows you to run some shell command or execute php-script in a different process.

To run exact function in a thread try look at PHP [Thread class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php)

Comment: would be some thing like this: [multithreading](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/), but the problem is, that it needs to run on windows